# Why do I get Unpermitted parameters with HABTM Association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently starting to build an open-source shop-catalog application.

I have `FunShop` and `FunSubcategory` models joined though a `FunSubcategorization` model with a `has_many :through` assosiation. In the `FunShop` form I added `Subcategory` checkboxes in this manner.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= hidden_field_tag "fun_shop[fun_subcategory_ids][]", nil %>
    <% FunSubcategory.all.each do |category| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "fun_shop[fun_subcategory_ids][]", category.id, @fun_shop.fun_subcategory_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.title %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

When I submit the form the error `Unpermitted parameters: fun_subcategory_ids` appears.

I know a little about strong parameters and I suspect there is a problem with that.
In my `FunShop` controller I have this:

```
def fun_shop_params
  params.require(:fun_shop).permit(:fun_subcategory_ids)
end  #Most code ommited for simplicity
```

And I have also done this in my FunShop model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fun_subcategorizations
```

There is a relevant repository at [My first web app](https://github.com/vasspilka/lamiatodo/tree/models).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved.

I needed to add this:

```
params.require(:fun_shop).permit(fun_subcategory_ids: [])
```

to specify that it was an Array.

Comment: this is the alias,
`params.require(:fun_shop).permit(fun_subcategory_ids: [])`